# Add existing plots to facet_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list column data frame with some plots e.g.

```
exdata <- diamonds %>% group_by(cut) %>% nest %>% crossing(dummy = 1:3) %>% 
+   mutate(plots = map(.x = data, ~ ggplot(.x, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()))
> exdata
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   cut       data                  dummy plots 
   <ord>     <list>                <int> <list>
 1 Fair      <tibble [1,610 × 9]>      1 <gg>  
 2 Fair      <tibble [1,610 × 9]>      2 <gg>  
 3 Fair      <tibble [1,610 × 9]>      3 <gg>  
 4 Good      <tibble [4,906 × 9]>      1 <gg>  
 5 Good      <tibble [4,906 × 9]>      2 <gg>  
 6 Good      <tibble [4,906 × 9]>      3 <gg>  
 7 Very Good <tibble [12,082 × 9]>     1 <gg>  
 8 Very Good <tibble [12,082 × 9]>     2 <gg>  
 9 Very Good <tibble [12,082 × 9]>     3 <gg>  
10 Premium   <tibble [13,791 × 9]>     1 <gg>  
11 Premium   <tibble [13,791 × 9]>     2 <gg>  
12 Premium   <tibble [13,791 × 9]>     3 <gg>  
13 Ideal     <tibble [21,551 × 9]>     1 <gg>  
14 Ideal     <tibble [21,551 × 9]>     2 <gg>  
15 Ideal     <tibble [21,551 × 9]>     3 <gg>
```

There's now 15 ggplots in `exdata$plots`. I would like to mimick the functionality of `ggplot2::facet_grid` where I have each plot laid out in a specified grid format.

Specifically I wouldlike the cut horizontal from left to right and then reading down field dummy as the vertical.

If I was building the plots from a single df I'd do something like `df %>% facet_grid(rows = dummy, columns = cut)`.

Is it possible to use facetgrid with existing plots as opposed to using this function based on a creating plots from a single data frame? If yes, how? If no, how can I lay my ggplots out in grid fashion as described above?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(patchwork)
exdata %>% 
  arrange(dummy) %>% 
  pull(plots) %>% 
  patchwork::wrap_plots(nrow = max(exdata$dummy))
```

I sort by `dummy` so that all the `dummy == 1` plots appear first. This should work fine if you have a fully-populated grid. If there are some missing combinations, I think you will need another solution, like the `geofacet` package, but that's really just a variation on `facet_grid` and would require the data be in one data frame.

[image]